# Opentok archiving issue?

Tags: android, html, ios, webrtc, opentok

I am facing a problem with archiving cost since the recording is very important,
so is there any way that I can store the video streams onto the server without the use of opentok startArchive method

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. The API method to start an archive is the only way to create archives and store them (after stopping them) on S3 or Azure.

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1 is precise; alternatively, you can develop and/or deploy your own media server and manage your own hosting webrtc compliant; you may still face bills from your cloud provider though...